# Search txt-files for exact numbers with batchfile, findstr

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file, regex, findstr

I'm trying to search for exact numbers stored in text files using a batch file. The files are looking like this:

```
1, 2, 4, 11, 18, 19, 25, 35, 42, 66, 87, 89.......
```

The problem is to avoid getting false positives, for instance when I do:

```
findstr "1" sometxtfile.txt > output
```

... it also finds the number 11 etc.

I solved this problem with the following:

```
findstr /R \<1\> sometxtfile.txt > output
```

But the numbers will have to be stored in variables, and when I do:

```
findstr /R "\<%variable%,\> sometxtfile.txt > output
```

... the command-line doesn't respond.

It has to be batch-only solution.

Comment: I think it would depend on what is in your variable.  Is it a number, a bunch of numbers etc?  Also If that is a copy and paste from your code you seem to be missing a closing quote (") after the expression should it be "\<%variable%,\>.  Another solution may be just to search for the number with the comma after it so your first example would be "1," instead of "1"

Answer (score 1):

For extract number with comma + space (or Tab) delimited:

```bath
@echo off 

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion 

for /f useback^tokens^=*delims^= %%i in (`type Q1597471.txt
`)do set "_line=%%~i" && for %%X in (!_line:^, ^= !)do echo=%%~X

endlocal & goto :eof
```

- Contents of the file `Q1597471.txt`...

```bath
0, 1, 2, 4, 11, 18, 19, 25, 35, 42, 66, 87, 89
10, 11, 12, 14, 111, 118, 119, 125, 135, 142, 166, 187, 189
210, 211, 212, 214, 2111, 2118, 2119, 2125, 2135, 2142, 2166, 2187, 2189
```

- Outputs:

```bath
0
1
2
4
11
18
19
25
35
42
66
87
89
10
11
12
14
111
118
119
125
135
142
166
187
189
210
211
212
214
2111
2118
2119
2125
2135
2142
2166
2187
2189
```

---

---

For a different understanding of mine (probably wrong), it would be to get all numbers on the same line concatenated.

---

```bath
@echo off 

cd /d "%~dp0"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /f useback^tokens^=*delims^= %%N in (`type Q1597471.txt`)do set/a "_cnt=1" & for /f %%X in ('
%ComSpec% /u /c set/p "'=%%~N"^<nul^|find.exe /v " "^|findstr.exe [0-9]^|find.exe /v /c ""
')do for /f %%n in ('%ComSpec%/u/c set/p "'=%%~N"^<nul^|find.exe /v " "^|findstr.exe [0-9]
')do if %%~X equ 1 (echo\%%~n) else if %%~X equ !_cnt! (echo=!_n: =!%%~n && set "_n="
     ) else (set /a "_cnt+=1" && call set "_n=!_n!%%~n")
    
endlocal & goto :eof
```

This alphabet soup in synthesis will:

1. Take line by line and count the occurrences of numbers
2. The flow per line will give the number of digits I need to extract/compose per line
3. The number of digits tells me how many times per loop (in the last) I will answer concatenating the output of the variable (digit by digit)

If I don't understand, let me know, my English is terrible squared...
The current in/out is some like:

Line in: `1, 2, 4, 11, 18, 19, 25, 35, 42, 66, 87, 89`
Line out `124111819253542668789`

---

**Obs.: 1.** Tested in a file containing a `comma` + `Tab` and containing `comma` + `space`.

**Obs.: 2.** Put the bat in the same folder and edit the file name `Q1597471.txt` for the file name/target.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to use regular expressions for this. If the files are always looking like this and the format is stable then just use a normal literal string match

```
findstr /C:" %variable%," sometxtfile.txt
```

The `/C` option is required to make it match spaces. But it needs every file to end with a `,` so you might have to append `,` to the end of them. If you can't do that then you need to use a real regex engine because it looks like there's some issue with `findstr`. PowerShell has that because it's already included in .NET. Why does it have to be batch-only? PowerShell is available everywhere for more than a decade and you just need this simple line:

```
powershell -C "Select-String '\b%variable%\b' sometxtfile.txt"
```

The command might need some tuning if you want to change the output format

---

Note that this command of yours `findstr /R \<1\> sometxtfile.txt > output` **doesn't work**. It gives the below error

> The system cannot find the file specified.

That's because `<` is recognized as an input redirector. You must quote it like this `findstr /R "\<1\>" sometxtfile.txt` or escape it `findstr /R \^<1\^> sometxtfile.txt`. But either of them makes `findstr` hang infinitely for some reason

There are also errors in the last command

```
                           ↓ Missing closing quote
findstr /R "\<%variable%,\> sometxtfile.txt > output
                        ↑ why comma here but not in the above command?
```